# Testing items in a list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor, e2e-testing

I want to test that the items added to a list have some kind of value in them. My current test looks like:

```
containerDetail.openItemAddModal();

element(by.css('[ng-click="form.section = \'batch\'"]')).click();
element(by.model(batchModel)).sendKeys(batchEntry); // we insert the batch items here
element(by.buttonText('Add')).click();
expect(element.all(by.repeater('item in detail.container.items')).count()).toEqual(6);

// Would like to test that each item has some text
// thinking something like this:    
element.all(by.repeater('item in detail.container.items')).each(function(item) {
    item.getText().then(function(text) {
        expect(text).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

I've been googling for a good way to do this, but haven't come up with anything.

Comment: Could you show what is `containerDetail.items()` and define "Parts below this do not work"? Thanks.

Comment: Sure. Updated question with more clarity around these items

Comment: Thanks, what about the current approach? Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`each()` fits perfectly here. I would use `toBeNonEmptyString()` matcher from [`jasmine-matchers`](https://github.com/JamieMason/Jasmine-Matchers) to assert there is a non empty text:

```
element.all(by.repeater('item in detail.container.items')).each(function(item) {
    expect(item.getText()).toBeNonEmptyString();
});
```

Also, if you know the expected values added to the list, you can use [`map()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map):

```
var items = element.all(by.repeater('item in detail.container.items')).map(function (item) {
    return item.getText();
});
expect(items).toEqual(["Value 1", "Value 2", "Value 3", "Value 4", "Value 5", "Value 6"]);
```

Comment: I think this would work, the only issue is the suite doesn't seem to be stopping for the expects to finish. The error I get is 'Failed: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document'.

Comment: @JPRO yeah, this is because the page changed after the new items were added and you need to "refind" the items..

Comment: Yeah I guess my issue is more that than this test. Your code looks good though, thanks for the answer.